# BackGround Thread with timer for application level-WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, scheduler

I have a wpf application(No MVVM), this application requires several background thread(Runs with specific time interval).

These thread should be on Application Level i.e. if user is on any WPF Window, these threads should be active.

Basically these thread will are using external resources so locking is also required.

Kindly tell me the best way to do this.

Comment: What are the background threads supposed to do?

Comment: For Example - A Thread will sync database values from server to local  .xml file

Comment: Why can't you just start them in `AppStartup` then?

Comment: Will it continually do it in a loop? At a predefined interval? When the UI notifies it?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to execute an action periodically in a WPF application you can use the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class.

Put your code as the handler of the `Tick` event and set the `Interval` property to whatever you need. Something like:

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0); // execute every hour
dt.Start();

// Tick handler    
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code to execute periodically
}
```

Comment: One Doubt on this. Let say I write this code on MainWindow.Xaml.cs that is the statrtupURI, if user goes to Windows2.xaml will it thread remain active and still my code will execute after specified interval

Comment: Thanks Tudor ,
this code is seems perfect for my situation, it is working properly

Comment: Tudor,

I implemented on OnStart in App.xml.cs. I Created three DispatcherTimer Tread for 3 different task.

On my landing page of application I have login button. Due to these Thread Login Button hangs for some time.

When I Comment the dispatcher area my application is running very smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void InitializeDatabaseConnectionCheckTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer _timerNet = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timerNet.Tick += new EventHandler(DatabaseConectionCheckTimer_Tick);
        _timerNet.Interval = new TimeSpan(_batchScheduleInterval);
        _timerNet.Start();
    }
    private void InitializeApplicationSyncTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(AppSyncTimer_Tick);
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(_batchScheduleInterval);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void IntializeImageSyncTimer()
    {
        DispatcherTimer _imageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _imageTimer.Tick += delegate
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                ImagesSync.SyncImages();
            }
        };
        _imageTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(_batchScheduleInterval);
        _imageTimer.Start();
    }
```

These three threads a intialized on App_OnStart

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        try
        {
            _batchScheduleInterval = Convert.ToInt32(ApplicationConfigurationManager.Properties["BatchScheduleInterval"]);
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException err)
        {
            TextLogger.Log(err.Message);
        }

        Helper.SaveKioskApplicationStatusLog(Constant.APP_START);
        if (SessionManager.Instance.DriverId == null && _batchScheduleInterval!=0)
        {
            InitializeApplicationSyncTimer();
            InitializeDatabaseConnectionCheckTimer();
            IntializeImageSyncTimer();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `_batchScheduleInterval`?

Comment: It gets the value from App.Config File (1000)

Comment: And it blocks the UI thread immediately after this code runs?

Comment: yes, when I comment 

 //if (SessionManager.Instance.DriverId == null && //_batchScheduleInterval!=0)
    //    {
    //        InitializeApplicationSyncTimer();
   //         InitializeDatabaseConnectionCheckTimer();
   //         IntializeImageSyncTimer();
   //     }

Its work smoothly

Comment: Hmm this is strange. So it should execute every 1000 minutes or seconds?

Comment: So you are using 1000 ticks x 100 ns = 100 microseconds. Are you sure you want your updates to be so frequent?

Comment: No That was just for testing. I have convert and Now I Convert it into _
timer.Interval=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_batchScheduleInterval);

Yup again my UI is hanged(slightly)  when thread executes

Comment: The problem is that the code of the tick handler is placed in the dispatcher queue and gets executed on the UI thread. I suggest you use instead the `System.Threading.Timer` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx, which executes on a different thread.